# Labels not being detected when adding table of figures

Tags: microsoft-word

I've ensured that i have right clicked every picture and pressed the insert caption button on it. Left it as default then i got a "figure 1" underneath it. From that i changed "figure 1" to "figure 5.5.5.3: Source code". Now i click the insert table of figures button and it says no "No table of figures entries found." 
I have more then 60 figures and i really don't want to make a table for it manually. Any thoughts?

Comment: `changed "figure 1" to "figure 5.5.5.3:"` - actually `1` contain the field recognized as label. Instead of changing it manually change "numbering" of the caption.

Comment: So you're telling me because i changed the "1" therefore word no longer recognizes it as a figure and hence it can't generate a table for it?

Comment: Yes exactly.  There is a  field behind `1`, which (among other functionality) tells to Word that the paragraph is a caption.